# Split a list of dicts into 2 sepatate lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary items like below

```
 list = [   {   'address_building': '710',
    'address_coord': '[123, 456]',
    'address_id': '4d322fa8f552',
    'address_street': 'Avenue road',
    'address_zipcode': '560080'},
{   'grades_0_date': '2014-03-03T00:00:00.000Z',
    'grades_0_grade': 'A',
    'grades_0_score_x': 1,
    'grades_0_score_y': 2,
    'grades_1_date': '2011-11-23T00:00:00.000Z',
    'grades_1_grade': 'A',
    'grades_1_score_x': 11,
    'grades_1_score_y': 22,
    'grades_id': '4d322fa8f552'}]
```

Now I would like to split this list into two separate lists:

```
list1 = [   {   'address_building': '710',
        'address_coord': '[123, 456]',
        'address_id': '4d322fa8f552',
        'address_street': 'Avenue road',
        'address_zipcode': '560080'}]

list2 = [ {
  'grades_0_date': '2014-03-03T00:00:00.000Z',
        'grades_0_grade': 'A',
        'grades_0_score_x': 1,
        'grades_0_score_y': 2,
        'grades_1_date': '2011-11-23T00:00:00.000Z',
        'grades_1_grade': 'A',
        'grades_1_score_x': 11,
        'grades_1_score_y': 22,
        'grades_id': '4d322fa8f552'}]
```

My Approach : I tried to convert the two dicts into the list directly but I am not able to get it the right way.

Is there any way easy way to get this done.

Comment: `a, b = [data[0]], [data[1]]` Like this?

Comment: `list` is a built-in, avoid objects names like this

Comment: Generic solution: `lst1, lst2 = ([x] for x in data)`

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [list[0]]
list2 = [list[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is use indexes, considering the first list has the two desired items

```
list1 = [list[0]]
list2 = [list[1]]
```

Comment: Yeah but that's not a list.

Comment: Oh my mistake, didn't catch that.